# How to Statically Initialize Array Of Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, initialization

How do I Statically initialize an array of objects in Java?
A simple example of my intentions follows:

Say my object is

```java
public class FRIEND {
    String name;
    String phone;
}
```

My intent is to do something like the below which doesn't work (I've tried variations with no luck).

```java
static FRIEND[] MyFriends[] = {
    { "Bob",  "5551234" },
    { "Jack", "5716666" },
    { "Mary", "5341111" }
};
```

I'e found tons of examples of array initialization but they either (a) initialize arrays of primitives (e.g. int[]) or (b) use loops with explicit setting (e.g., MyFriends[n].name = "Bob");

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add a constructor to your class and put `new FRIEND(...)` in your array initialization.

Comment: I tried that but shouldn't it be "new FRIEND[]"? Also I am not sure about the syntax of the "..." in your suggestion. A more verbose example would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `FRIEND` objects

```
static FRIEND[] MyFriends = {
        new FRIEND("Bob", "5551234"),
        new FRIEND("Jack", "5716666"),
        new FRIEND("Mary", "5341111")
};
```

Add a constructor to the `FRIEND` class

```
public class FRIEND {
    String name;
    String phone;

    public FRIEND(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

The full code (with java 8)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class FRIEND {
    String name;
    String phone;

    static FRIEND[] MyFriends = {
            new FRIEND("Bob", "5551234"),
            new FRIEND("Jack", "5716666"),
            new FRIEND("Mary", "5341111")
    };

    public FRIEND(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FRIEND{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream(MyFriends).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Output

```
FRIEND{name='Bob', phone='5551234'}
FRIEND{name='Jack', phone='5716666'}
FRIEND{name='Mary', phone='5341111'}
```

Comment: worked perfectly! Thanks! Adding the constructor was the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can also use an enum like this:

```
public enum Friend
{
    BOB("Bob", "5551234"),
    JACK("Jack", "5716666"),
    MARY("Mary", "5341111");

    private String name;
    private String phone;

    Friend(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

Is another option that can use.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

As specified [in Oracle code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) "class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized", so instead of `FRIEND` better use `Friend` as your class name.
Your static `MyFriends` array will be rewritten as

```
public static Friend[] MyFriends = {
            new Friend("Bob", "5551234"),
            new Friend("Jack", "5716666"),
            new Friend("Mary", "5341111")
}
```

Above the code of the `Friend` class:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Friend {

    String name;
    String phone;

    public Friend(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Friend [name=" + name + ", phone=" + phone + "]";
    }

    public static Friend[] MyFriends = {
            new Friend("Bob", "5551234"),
            new Friend("Jack", "5716666"),
            new Friend("Mary", "5341111")
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Friend friend : MyFriends) {
            System.out.println(friend);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. In general, I always use camel-case naming for code-bearing classes. I still prefer all-caps for "data-only" classes like the original FRIEND class in my question. Probably a hangover from 30+ years of C/C++ coding. Oh well, old-dog/old-tricks :)